# no listening sockets available while starting httpd

Tags: centos6, httpd

Our server is configured with an internal IP. Then in the firewall, the admins mapped a valid IP address (2.X.Y.Z). So, the `ipconfig` command shows

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:E0:61:36:D5:34
          inet addr:172.20.54.10  Bcast:172.20.54.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::270:81ef:fec6:d534/64 Scope:Link
```

However, we use `ssh 2.X.Y.Z`. Now, I want to setup the apache web server in order to enter 2.X.Y.Z in the web browser. So, I opened `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and modified

```
Listen 2.X.Y.Z:80
Listen 80
```

I replaced the XYZ with the numbers. Problem is, when I restart the httpd, I get this error

```
Starting httpd: (99)Cannot assign requested address: make_sock: could not bind to address 2.X.Y.Z:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                       [FAILED]
```

UPDATE 1:

If I replace `Listen 2.X.Y.Z` with `Listen 172.20.54.10`, then I get this error

```
Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                       [FAILED]
```

If I comment that line, the service will be started. However, in the browser, the valid IP 2.X.Y.Z doesn't work. Instead, the internal IP `172.20.54.10` works. In other words, the apache test page is only shown from the local network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `2.X.Y.Z`

is *NOT* bind to `eth1` interface, yet `172.20.54.10` is, either comment out `Listen 2.X.Y.Z:80` line or replace `2.X.Y.Z` with `172.20.54.10` and then try to start your `httpd`.

---

> Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind
>   to address [::]:80 (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not
>   bind to address 0.0.0.0:80

that means there is another process that is already binded to port 80, and that's why httpd won't start.

> If I comment that line, the service will be started. However, in the
>   browser, the valid IP 2.X.Y.Z doesn't work. Instead, the internal IP
>   172.20.54.10 works. In other words, the apache test page is only shown from the local network.

`2.X.Y.Z` probably won't work, due to routing/firewall not due `httpd`

Comment: So, there was a stale process and I killed that. While it is `Listen 172.20.54.10:80` and the service started successfully, still the apache test page is shown from local network and when I enter `2.X.Y.Z` from outside of the campus, the apache test page is not shown

Comment: As I said, although the eth1 is configured as `172.20.54.10`, we are able to ssh from outside with `2.X.Y.Z`

Comment: again, this is due your firewall configuration / network routing ... most likely you will never be able to access your public address from within local network... public address can only be accessed from another public interface, period!

Comment: Should I delete the post?